# Rendering route, from product id, while passing in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Product.js component where I render a list of products (books),

```
export default class Product extends Component {
  render() {
console.log(this.props)


return (
<Router>
  <div>
    <div>
    {this.props.products.map(product =>(
    <div>
      <p>Products</p>
      <p>Id:{product.id}</p>
      <p>Title: {product.title}</p>
      <p>Info: <br/>{product.info}</p>
      <NavLink to={`/products/${product.id}`}>Details</NavLink>
      <br/>
      </div>
    ))}
    </div>
```

I then want to make a route, so that each product, has an attached link, to see the details of the book.

I want to make a conditional route, with the id, and then pass the values in as props

```
 <Route path="/:id" render={() => <Book />}
```

Here I'm in doubt, what I should pass in because I no longer have access to the props from the rendered products. Could I pass it in with the link, and should I make a nested route?

Here is my book component, which should be rendered, when a link of details is clicked for a book

```
export default function Book({ props}) {
  console.log(props)
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Book details go here</h1>
      <h3></h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```

EDIT:

i tried accesing the props like suggested

```
export default function Book(props) {
  console.log(props.match.id)
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Book details go here</h1>
      <h3></h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` should be accessible from the `match` prop that React Router sends down to the route component, i.e.

```
const id = this.props.match.params.id;
```

Also, your route should be

```
<Route path="/:id" component={Book} >
```

instead of

```
<Route path="/:id" render={() => <Book />} />
```

Comment: my bad - `this.props.match.params.id`

Comment: i don't recieve anything except the props, that was passed in `<Book products={this.props.products}`

Comment: The `match` prop should be available in the `Book` component

Comment: Yes, but it is not.. i will edit the question, i think the Route is wrong..

Comment: that might be it - try `component={Book}` instead of `render={() => <Book />}`

Comment: Yes did the trick, I just figured out my self haha. You can edit, the answer and I will accept, thank you for your help.